# Hide or Disable System Tray

Tags: c#

I am working in .Net Windows Application. My requirement is, through my code i want to disable or hide the SYSTEM TRAY...

I am not having any idea regarding this..Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to show/hide Windows taskbar you can use this:

```
public class Taskbar
{
    [DllImport( "user32.dll" )]
    private static extern int FindWindow( string className, string windowText );
    [DllImport( "user32.dll" )]
    private static extern int ShowWindow( int hwnd, int command );

    private const int SW_HIDE = 0;
    private const int SW_SHOW = 1;

    protected static int Handle
    {
        get { return FindWindow( "Shell_TrayWnd", "" ); }
    }

    private Taskbar() { }

    public static void Show()
    {
        ShowWindow( Handle, SW_SHOW );
    }

    public static void Hide()
    {
        ShowWindow( Handle, SW_HIDE );
    }
}
```

So you can use
`Taskbar.Show()` to show taskbar and
`Taskbar.Hide()` to hide it.

Comment: @RobinHood: is this what you need? Or you need something different?

Comment: Hi Marco, Thanks for your response...But i want to hide only my SYSTEM TRAY. not the whole TASKBAR...

Comment: @RobinHood: which OS are you using or targeting?